# React Navigation Tabs not found matching with content description

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, ui-testing

I'm trying to access Tab Components of Tab Navigator using `testID` or `accessibilityLabel`. It is working fine on iOS and Recording Tests on Xcode works.
But on android Test recorder doesn't capture `accessibilityLabel` or `testID`. Which are provided like following in Tab Component:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarTestIDProps: {
        testID            : "tasksTab",
        accessibilityLabel: "tasksTab"
    },
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <View accessible accessibilityLabel="tasksTabIcon" testID="tasksTabIcon">
            <TabIcon tintColor={tintColor} name="tasks" />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Trying to access `accessibilityLabel` in Android Test in Espresso with:

```
ViewInteraction tasksTab = onView(withContentDescription("tasksTab"));
```

results in error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with content description: is "tasksTab"
```

But if I access `tasksTabIcon` it works but action `click()` has no joy on it. Also I have to select the 1st element as it finds multiple instances for `tasksTabIcon`.

```
ViewInteraction tasksTab = onView(first(withContentDescription("tasksTabIcon")));
tasksTab.perform(click());
```

I've also checked it with **Layout Inspector** but the behavior is the same. Label for `tasksTabIcon` is present but label for `tasksTab` is not.

- react-navigation | 1.5.11
- react-navigation-redux-helpers | 1.0.5
- react-native     | 0.51.0
- node             | 9.5.0
- npm or yarn | 5.6.0 / 1.5.1

Comment: Can you tell me what you used for access to it in iOS ? None of them worked `app.toolbarButtons["navigateProject"].tap()
 app.otherElements["navigateProject"].tap()
 app.buttons["navigateProject"].tap()` where navigateProject is my `testID`

Comment: It could be different depending up you setup of Nav and version of React Navigation but I just recorded the tests with Xcode and they work.